# Nothing is outputting

Tags: javascript

I don't know what I am doing wrong, I can't get any output. Language is javascript.

Heres the question

> Write a program that determines how many males and females live in each
>   of the Zip Code areas in the Student Enrollment Records Set. Output
>   the zip code, the total number of males, and the total number of
>   females for each zip code. At the end of the report display a total of
>   males and females.
>
> There are 5 zip codes in the record set. The zip codes are : 53711,
>   53712, 53713, 53714, 53716. These zipcode values are self-evident as
>   zipcodes, and may be used as literals within the program--they are an
>   exception to the general course standard of avoiding the use of
>   literals down in the main section of a program. As each record is
>   read, interrogate the gender code field and the zip code field, and
>   then increment the appropriate counter variables for that gender and
>   for that gender and zipcode combination.
>
> There must be at least five (5) functions.
>
> The output needs to look like this
>
> ```
> 53711: Males: 5 Females: 2 
> 53712: Males: 9 Females: 9 
> 53713: Males: 11 Females: 3 
> 53714: Males: 4 Females: 6 
> 53716: Males: 1 Females: 0 
>
> Total Males: 30 
> Total Females: 20
> ```

Heres my code

```
/*
    Main Function
*/

function getStudentRecords() {

    //constants
    var ZERO = 0;
    var MALE = "M";
    var FEMALE = "F";
    var ZIPCODE_ONE = 53711;
    var ZIPCODE_TWO = 53712;
    var ZIPCODE_THREE = 53713;
    var ZIPCODE_FOUR = 53714;
    var ZIPCODE_FIVE = 53716;

    //global variables

    var totalFemales;
    var totalMales;
    var currentName;
    var currentZipCode;
    var currentGender;
    var studentRecords;
    var malesZipcodeOne;
    var femalesZipcodeOne;
    var malesZipcodeTwo;
    var femalesZipcodeTwo;
    var malesZipcodeThree;
    var femalesZipcodeThree;
    var malesZipcodeFour;
    var femalesZipcodeFour;
    var malesZipcodeFive;
    var femalesZipcodeFive;

    function displayZipcodeData() {

        document.write(ZIPCODE_ONE);
        document.write(" : Males ");
        document.write(malesZipcodeOne);
        document.write(" : Females ");
        document.write(femalesZipcodeOne);
        document.write("<br />");
        document.write(ZIPCODE_TWO);
        document.write(" : Males ");
        document.write(malesZipcodeTwo);
        document.write(" : Females ");
        document.write(femalesZipcodeTwo);
        document.write("<br />");
        document.write(ZIPCODE_THREE);
        document.write(" : Males ");
        document.write(malesZipcodeThree);
        document.write(" : Females ");
        document.write(femalesZipcodeThree);
        document.write("<br />");
        document.write(ZIPCODE_FOUR);
        document.write(" : Males ");
        document.write(malesZipcodeFour);
        document.write(" : Females ");
        document.write(femalesZipcodeFour);
        document.write("<br />");
        document.write(ZIPCODE_FIVE);
        document.write(" : Males ");
        document.write(malesZipcodeFive);
        document.write(" : Females ");
        document.write(femalesZipcodeFive);
        document.write("<br />");

    }

    function processStudentRecords() {

        while (studentRecords.readNextRecord()) {
            currentZipCode = studentRecords.getStudentZipCode();
            currentGender = studentRecords.getStudentGender();

            if (currentZipCode === ZIPCODE_ONE) {

                if (currentGender === MALE) {
                    malesZipCodeOne++;
                    totalMales++;
                } else {
                    femalesZipCodeOne++;
                    totalFemales++;
                }

            }
            if (currentZipCode === ZIPCODE_TWO) {

                if (currentGender === MALE) {
                    malesZipCodeTwo++;
                    totalMales++;
                } else {
                    femalesZipCodeTwo++;
                    totalFemales++;
                }

            }

            if (currentZipCode === ZIPCODE_THREE) {

                if (currentGender === MALE) {
                    malesZipCodeThree++;
                    totalMales++;
                } else {
                    femalesZipCodeThree++;
                    totalFemales++;
                }

            }
            if (currentZipCode === ZIPCODE_FOUR) {

                if (currentGender === MALE) {
                    malesZipCodeFour++;
                    totalMales++;
                } else {
                    femalesZipCodeFour++;
                    totalFemales++;
                }

            }
            if (currentZipCode === ZIPCODE_FIVE) {

                if (currentGender === MALE) {
                    malesZipCodeFive++;
                    totalMales++;
                } else {
                    femalesZipCodeFive++;
                    totalFemales++;
                }

            }


        }

    }

    function initializeEnrollmentRecords() {
        studentRecords = openStudentEnrollmentRecords();

        totalFemales = ZERO;
        totalMales = ZERO;
        totalStudents = ZERO;
        malesZipcodeOne = ZERO;
        femalesZipcodeOne = ZERO;
        malesZipcodeTwo = ZERO;
        femalesZipcodeTwo = ZERO;
        malesZipcodeThree = ZERO;
        femalesZipcodeThree = ZERO;
        malesZipcodeFour = ZERO;
        femalesZipcodeFour = ZERO;
        malesZipcodeFive = ZERO;
        femalesZipcodeFive = ZERO;


    }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors? What debugging steps have you tried already? We really need a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), not hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: You can construct a single string and write it once.. also take a look at arras and possibly cases. Anyway.

Comment: `var ZERO = 0;` Just in case the value of `ZERO` ever changes!

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of your other problems, you are not calling `displayZipCodeData()` anywhere, so that code is not being executed.